# window.location.hash work-around for chrome / angular2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, location, angular2-forms

I have a complex form which I have simplified for the purpose of this question and hosted as a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/8GCeAecbZBs4qBn53JmW?p=preview).

Three onclick functions for 'edit' `openEditor(i: number, isEditor: boolean)`, ‘add’ and ‘save changes’ `moveToItem()` all use window.location.hash
to navigate to an editor which is otherwise hidden when inactive.

It works as expected but not in chrome.
I gather it's to do with chrome doing a page refresh since it considers hash changes as generating a new URL

**Question:**

**Can someone offer a relatively simple fix that will work for chrome (and in the [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/8GCeAecbZBs4qBn53JmW?p=preview))?**

Failing that what is the best approach to manage the editor within the form?

I thought about creating a separate child component for the editor  as there’s a lot going on in the FormComponent) but not sure that would help resolve this issue as I would still need to navigate to the point in the page where it sits and then back to the appropriate data.

The editor needs to exist within the form and access/update the form data.

**Some things I have tried:**

setting the hash to blank or null before:

```
window.location.hash = null;
window.location.hash = '';
```

Prepending the # on the value

```
window.location.hash = '#form-editor';
```

also:

```
(<HTMLScriptElement>document.querySelector('#' + 'form-editor')).scrollIntoView();
```

and with pushState I can alter the url but it does not move to the anchor point:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, '#form-editor');


window.history.replaceState(null, null, '#form-editor');
```

**Additional info:**

The ‘add’ function is to add a new item in the list after the item selected

Anchor point for form-editor is:

```
<div id="form-editor">
```

and a dynamic id is created for each item number:

```
<div id="item{{i}}">Item: {{i}}</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: seems to work just fine in chrome: https://run.plnkr.co/W2v44MKOg3FovLYr/

Comment: hmm. it wasn’t working for me when I tried your link a moment ago (and using latest version of chrome). Also just clicked again and that link is currently Not Found. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On a Chrome refresh bug (derived from Safari), I read that only a click on an anchor - with `href` pointing to the hash place we want - would work. So, we must code something that would do it, like this starting `body`:

> ```
> <body unbeforeunload="whereWeWantToScroll.click()">
>   <a id="whereWeWantToScroll" href="#form-editor" style="display: none">
>     Reposition to the right place
>   </a>
> ```

In this example, the anchor is hidden but should rather be `position: fixed` if there's just the `unbeforeunload` that triggers it.